# You Tube Video not autoplay in mobile browser

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I have making a website with a youtube video background. The video is autoplaying in desktop browesr but not autoplaying in mobile browser.
My code is:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uv2Sj4rSq3A?autoplay=1&loop=1&showinfo=0" class="fill" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's known fact that youtube video can't be auto-play on mobile. Here is the warning https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

> Due to this restriction, functions and parameters such as autoplay,
>   playVideo(), loadVideoById() won't work in all mobile environments.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any idea to play video on mobile browser when page lode will completed?